# Which virtual alias concepts of Postfix can be migrated to Microsoft Exchange how?

Tags: postfix, exchange

My company uses some pretty basic Postfix setup, but makes heavily use of virtual aliases of different kinds. One example is using regular expressions to map special mail addresses of different test users for all kinds of different software tests to the mail addresses of the testers. This allows testers to easily create new recipient addresses as necessary without any admin to do something.

```
# Sometimes one needs lots of different mail addresses for debugging purposes and the following
# simply maps all of those to one existing account, while keeping recipients as provided somewhere.
/^tschoening\.test.+?@am-soft\.de$/ tschoening@am-soft.de
```

For various reasons, we need to migrate to some Microsoft Exchange now and therefore need to check which of the concepts we use can be implemented by Exchange or which need other approaches in the future. Sadly, I currently don't even know the version of that Exchange, only that it's "somewhat current". I wasn't able to find a good overview of which things map how, so thought I'm simply asking here and maybe starting such an overview.

**So, which virtual alias concepts of Postfix can be migrated to Microsoft Exchange how?**

Comment: Regular expressions might be added by custom implementation using a transport agent:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/61766eea-e088-4b09-8fea-9abf0e7b2ab1/wildcard-aliases?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy

Comment: Office 365 seems to support regular expressions OOTB and mentions that those are implemented using PowerShell. So the latter might be available on-premise as well: https://serverfault.com/questions/827954/microsoft-exchange-mail-rule-allows-regular-expressions-but-which-ones

Comment: Hi, it's been a long time, is there any update? Please check if the below info is helpful to you. If your problem has been fixed, you could mark the best answer or share your solutions. Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, I found a guide in **GitHub**: **[exchange-active-directory-to-postfix-map](https://github.com/eLvErDe/exchange-active-directory-to-postfix-map)**, the script in it is used to Exchange emails addresses from Active Directory to a Postfix map.

"**This project is a Python3 script that connects to Active Directory using LDAP protocol and extracts from there every email address found in Exchange related attributes. Then it will turn this into a Postfix map and uses it as a whitelist for "smtpd_recipient_restrictions" postfix configuration setting.**"

Hope it's helpful to you!

Comment: Exchange to Postfix is the wrong direction, I need replacements for what Postifx provides in Exchange.